# Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cryptography

I have hashed the user password using `Crypto.HashPassword('nakedPassword');` and saved this value in my db.

During signup:

```
public Status Signup(Customer user) 
{
    //change password to password hash & create a verification codetry 
    try 
    {
        int pkid;
        user.PASSWORD = Crypto.HashPassword(user.PASSWORD);
        user.VER_CODE = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Mapper.CreateMap <Customer,user>();
        var mappedcustomer = Mapper.Map<Customer,user>(user);
        string result = _userRepository.Signup(mappedcustomer);
        Status status = new Status();
        if (result == "MOB_EXISTS") 
        {
            status.setError("Mobile number already exists");
        } 
        else if (result == "EMAIL_EXISTS") 
        {
            status.setError("Email already exists");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Later during login when i retrieve using:

```
Status status = new Status();
try
{
    string hashedPass = _userRepository.GetHashedPassByEmail(email);
    if (Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPass, password)) //<-- THIS LINE THROWS THE EXCEPTION
    {
        //authenticated
        status.setSuccess("Login successful !");
    }
    else
    {
        status.setError("Invalid Credentials. Please try again.");
    }

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    status.setError("Error during login. Please check the credentials and try again.");
}
```

The pointed line throws the exception

> System.FormatException
>
> Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.
>
> Stacktrace:
>
> at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32
>   inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)    at
>   System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
>   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)    at
>   System.Web.Helpers.Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(String hashedPassword,
>   String password)    at Tmmmt.Business.UserProvider.login(String email,
>   String password) in
>   c:\Users\MacBook\Source\Repos\tmmmt.com\Tmmmt.Business\UserProvider.cs:line
>   802

**Note:** This does not happen all the time but happens on certain signups only.
See **[`Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto.verifyhashedpassword%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)**

### Edit

When I looked into my code for signup I saw a hash getting generated but it is truncated when writing to db.

For example:

**Actual Hash:** 
ANFRzzPtJ6H/hmsxmbPpkUgIDcmxoaWDV6Ej8Xes8+PupKnsKq3EI/cUTHCRZm9t+g==

**Hash in Db:**
ANFRzzPtJ6H/hmsxmbPpkUgIDcmxoaWDV6Ej8Xes8+PupKnsKq

The password field in the db is `varchar(8000)` and I am putting it through the following way:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<string> sp_signupweb(string name, string email, string passHash, string code, Nullable<long> mob, Nullable<int> utc, string verifycode, ObjectParameter result) 

{

    ...//some code//

     var passHashParameter = passHash != null ?
                    new ObjectParameter("passHash", passHash) :
                    new ObjectParameter("passHash", typeof(string));

    //.... some more code
                return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<string>("sp_signupweb", nameParameter, emailParameter, passHashParameter, codeParameter, mobParameter, utcParameter, verifycodeParameter, result);

}
```

How does the truncation occur?

Comment: Well what value are you passing in? Presumably, as the exception says, it's basically not valid base64... Bear in mind that we have no idea what `GetHashedPassByEmail` is doing.

Comment: So `hashedPass` is not in a valid base64 format, are you stripping the padding  `=` when you generate it?

Comment: as the code implies i am passing the hashedPassword and the naked password during login to check whether the entered password is valid or not.. this works for many accounts but for some combo it throws this exception

Comment: @AlexK. I have shown how i am saving the hashed key on signup in my new edit... and no i am not doing any stripping

Comment: Sounds like the hash is not a base64 string, but I assume you use the HashPassword method to generate the Hash. And according to MSDN that method is supposed to generate a Base64 string. I would look into 1. is this consistently happening for the same users, 2.  Do you loose some encoding information when you store the Hash in your database (the most probable cause I would say)

Comment: @JesperNiedermann 1.Yes 2.I am not sure.. how do i check ? Note that i am not html encoding anything anywhere,,

Comment: @JonSkeet `GetHashedPassByEmail` simply gets the hashed password stored in db for the passed email id.

Comment: Well then you should look at the value that's in the database...

Comment: I am getting exactly same hashed password which is stored in the db. @JonSkeet

Comment: @Nezam: And what is that value? (As I asked nearly an hour ago...)

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry for the delayed response.. was investigating this matter.. please everyone check my edit now.. seems like the hash generated is correct but it is truncated when written to db (during signup) and hence the login hash check fails..

Comment: Right. So hence why I asked for the value right at the very start... so it sounds like your database schema may have a length restriction on the field...

Comment: If the field length is ok, check the declared *@parameter* length in `sp_signupweb`

Comment: I mean WOW.. just WOW.. the length restriction in `sp_signupweb` was 50!! Thanks man.. let me check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing the parameter length of stored procedure (signup) fixed it for me.